# Jasmine-node tests executed twice

Tags: node.js, tdd, jasmine, jasmine-node

My jasmine-node tests are executed twice.

I run those test from Grunt task and also from Jasmine command. Result is the same my tests are run twice.
My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.x",
    "mongodb": "~2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-jasmine-node":"~0.3.1 "
  }
}
```

Here is my Gruntfile.js extract :

```
    grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine_node: {
      options: {
        forceExit: true,
        match: '.',
        matchall: true,
        extensions: 'js',
        specNameMatcher: 'spec'
      },
      all: ['test/']
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-node');
  grunt.registerTask('jasmine', 'jasmine_node');
```

One of my test file :

```
describe("Configuration setup", function() {
    it("should load local configurations", function(next) {
        var config = require('../config')();
        expect(config.mode).toBe('local');
        next();
    });
    it("should load staging configurations", function(next) {
        var config = require('../config')('staging');
        expect(config.mode).toBe('staging');
        next();
    });
    it("should load production configurations", function(next) {
        var config = require('../config')('production');
        expect(config.mode).toBe('production');
        next();
    });
});
```

I have 2 test files for 4 assertions

Here is my prompt :

```
grunt jasmine
Running "jasmine_node:all" (jasmine_node) task
........

Finished in 1.781 seconds
8 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

Have you got any idea ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately no, then I moved to mocha test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit to [1.618](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1884140/1-618). He answered the question here: [grunt jasmine-node tests are running twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117965/grunt-jasmine-node-tests-are-running-twice)

This looks likes some buggy behaviour. The quick fix is to configure `jasmine_node` in your `Gruntfile` like this:

```
jasmine_node: {
    options: {
        forceExit: true,
        host: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/',
        match: '.',
        matchall: false,
        extensions: 'js',
        specNameMatcher: '[sS]pec'
    },
    all: []
}
```

The key is the `all` parameter. The `grunt` plugin is looking for files with *spec* in the name. For some reason, it looks in the `spec/` directory *and* everywhere else. If you specify the `spec` directory, its files get picked up twice. If you don't specify, it only gets set once, but then you can't put *spec* in any of your non-test filenames.