# grunt jasmine-node tests are running twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, jasmine-node

I set up grunt to run node.js jasmine tests. For some reason, with this config, the results always show double the tests.

Here is my config:

I'm using [jasmine-node](https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node) which plugs into grunt.

**/spec/some-spec.js**:

```
var myModule = require('../src/myModule.js');
describe('test', function(){
     it('works', function(done){
         setTimeout(function(){
             expect(1).toBe(1);
             done();
         }, 100);
     });
});
```

**Gruntfile.js**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        jasmine_node: {
            options: {
                forceExit: true
            },
            all: ['spec/']
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-node');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jasmine_node']);
};
```

This results in *two* tests running rather than one.

```
> grunt
Running "jasmine_node:all" (jasmine_node) task
..

Finished in 0.216 seconds
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) project is pretty old.  The latest [commit](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/commit/6c6099b6a33ae65b5b3c9a141e75ea797fa95a69) is from July of 2014.  The [grunt-jasmine-node](https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node) plugin appears to be active, but running against something that is going stale seems a little pointless IMHO.

To test CommonJS modules using Jasmine I'd recommend using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) along with the 
[karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) and [karma-commonjs](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs) plugins.  I got your example working with the following files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-jasmine-node": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-commonjs": "0.0.13",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4"
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
  basePath: '.',
  frameworks: ['jasmine', 'commonjs'],
  files: [{
        pattern: 'src/**/*.js'
      }, {
        pattern: 'spec/**/*.js'
      }],

  preprocessors: {
    'src/**/*.js': ['commonjs'],
    'spec/**/*.js': ['commonjs']
  },

  reporters: ['progress'],

  browsers: ['PhantomJS']
  });
};
```

**Gruntfile.js** (optional if you still want to use grunt)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        options: {
          singleRun: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['karma:unit']);
};
```

You should also install the karma command line runner globally, just like you probably did with grunt.  `npm install -g karma-cli`

From your command line you can start karma by typing `karma start`.  It will run the tests and then watch your files and re-run them on every save. (VERY NICE)

Alternatively you can run `karma start --single-run` to have it just run your tests once and exit.  If you also updated your Gruntfile you can also just run `grunt` to run the tests once.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce the behavior.  This is what seems to be happening:

1. The task looks in the specified folder (`spec` in your case) for files with *spec* in the name.
2. Then it looks again in *every* folder in the whole project for files with *spec* in the name.

What it ends up with is 2 overlapping sets of test files to run.

My first attempt at trying to coerce it into more logical behavior was to set `specNameMatcher: null` (default is 'spec'), and leave the folder set to 'spec/'.  This results in no tests being run, since apparently both conditions (name and folder) must be met for files in the specified folder.  You get the same problem if `specNameMatcher` is left at the default value, but the files in the folder don't have 'spec' in the name.

What *does* work is to set the folder (or 'test set' or whatever you want to call it) to `[]`:

```
    jasmine_node: {
        options: {
            forceExit: true
        },
        all: []
    }
```

The catch is that if you have *any* other files somewhere else in the project with 'spec' in the name, they'll be mistaken for tests by jasmine.

I would consider this behavior a bug, and it should probably be reported via the project's github issues page.

Answer (score 3):

This grunt plugin ( https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node ) seems to be dead ( https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-node/issues/60 ).

Maybe it is a better to switch to https://github.com/onury/grunt-jasmine-nodejs ?

Comment: What exactly leads you to believe that the project is "dead"?

Answer (score 2):

The current up voted answer isn't the solution. You simply modify the expression that's going to match your tests. The answer is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine_node: {
        options: {
            forceExit: true
        },
        all: ['spec/*spec.js']
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-node');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jasmine_node']);
};
```

Here you can see that 'all' is set to ***'spec/*spec.js'***. This will search for all tests.

Secondly, just because a project hasn't had a recently commit, doesn't mean it's "old". jasmine-node is simply stable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using grunt-jasmine-node, and as aeryaguzov points out, that project is no longer maintained.  Switching to grunt-jasmine-node-new solves the issue for me.

grunt-jasmine-node-new is a fork of grunt-jasmine-node that is actively maintained, and can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jasmine-node-new